# Error: Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50): No cached version available for offline

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

Please, I just created a new project with kotlin on android studio 3.5, its giving me this error:" Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50): No cached version available for offline "
I cannot do anything as the gradle will not sync successfully, please does anyone know how to resolve this please??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562953

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No cached version... available for offline mode."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode)

Comment: thanks for reaching out... i have followed that and I get a new error:Could not set unknown property 'plugin' for root project 'kotlin_app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: thanks for reaching out, but it did not. I got this error again after following that step: Could not set unknown property 'plugin' for root project 'kotlin_app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Thanks @itwasntme, it solved the issue, i had to "invalidate caches/restart", then "sync project with gradle files" again.

Comment: TWIMC, You can use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844064/1164529 as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **re-enable** your Gradle online mode then sync project with Gradle files.
Tod do this,

1. Navigate to Gradle scripts.
2. Click on build.gradle, a window will open.
3. To re-enable Gradle online mode, click on the last but one icon(like a switch symbol) shown on the screenshot below.

[image: re-enalbe Gradle online mode]

4. After this, navigate to files in your android studio and click on "*sync project with Gradle file*" and you will be good to go.

Comment: didnt get re-enable option

Answer (score 0):

View->ToolWindows->Gradle click on toogle offline mode