# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, augmented-reality, gradle-plugin

I am facing this issue many times when i download project from github
i am using new Android studio(bumble bee)
please help me if any body knows

https://github.com/fjbatresv/arcore_solar_system.git (this is the project which i am downloading in bumble bee)

There are not any gradle issue

actually i have tried many solutions from stack over flow but i am getting solutions for gradle but it is not an gradle related error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 145):

Upgrade your `com.android.tools.build:gradle` in your `build.gradle` file to the latest version

e.g.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
```

And upgrade your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to the latest version i.e.

```
#Tue Apr 12 23:39:17 AEST 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Optionally, you can upgrade it using Project-Structure UI

[image]

Comment: It also needs JDK 11 or above to be used. So please update that as well if you apply the above solution.

Comment: To update the project to compile with Java 11, goto Android Studio ➔ File ➔ Project Structure ➔ SDK Location ➔ click Gradle Settings ➔ Gradle JDK = 11

Comment: What if you can't or don't want to update? It's pretty concerning how "just update to the latest" has become a commonly recommended (and readily accepted) "fix" for things that should have never been broken in the first place. In this case, the root cause was very likely a mistake, as described by @dont-panic below, and can be resolved without changing any versions.

Comment: Rather than just update to the latest, the com.android.tools.build:gradle version number should match the latest patch version of the plugin that corresponds to the version of Gradle being run... which can be found here: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
So if you are using Gradle 7.3.3, for example, you need the plugin version to be 7.2.x
You can find all the plugin versions at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google - and so select 7.2.2
Perhaps I should make this a separate answer?

Answer (score 19):

Upgrade your Android Gradle plugin version to 4.0.1 or higher in the project `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
        ...
    }
}
```

Upgrade the Gradle version to 6.5 or higher in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 16):

I was facing same issue and solved it with following changes

In File -> Project Structure, set Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.0.3
And Gradle Version 7.0.2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

For me I resolved by

Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location > Gradle Settings.

Check there Gradle JDK, try changing it and then sync again.

[image: solution]

Comment: Note: that to find the gradle settings there is a text link
 "JDK Location was moved to "Gradle Settings" 
You can see part of this text link in the screen shot just behind the pop-up

Answer (score 5):

I also faced similar issue. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
Finally i was able to fix this issue, by Go To File>>Settings>>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools
And I am enable "Reload project after changes in the build scripts">Any changes
after this Appeared new Error "Add Google maven repository"
I add Google maven repository to build.gradle and project worked without any errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aglKI.png)

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem after digging into the source code and some experiments.

Android SDK configuration file `~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/package.xml` has an extra tag named `base-extension` compared to the same file of other API levels. Removing this tag solves the problem.

Delete downloaded `Android API 32` SDK Platform from SDK Manager (`Tools` → `SDK Manager`) also solves the problem (you can redownload after deletion). Maybe the Android studio team noticed the problem, redownloading API 32 platform files, the `base-extension` tag disappeared from the API 32 `package.xml`

[image: the extra tag in android-32/package.xml (after format the file)]

> ↑ the extra tag in android-32/package.xml (after formatting the file)

Comment: Wow that's a great find. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, one of my classpath depencencies had double quotes, once I changed it to single quotes, it worked fine.

Example, change:
`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1"`

To:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'`