# No cached version of androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Could not determine the dependencies of task `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac.`

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2 available for offline mode.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no cached version available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409265/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode)

Comment: toggle the value of Offline Mode from menu bar `View > Tool Windows > Gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio:

> File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings

or in OSX:

> Preferences -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Setting