# Andriod Gradle Sync failed offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode.

Comment: Bad description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no cached version available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409265/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android studio 3.6 location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel

Comment: i do this step and turn on offline mode

Comment: 1 you can't find offline mode in setting and you need to find gradle in  Did you do it?