# Could not download builder.jar Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Well, I updated to Android Studio 4.0 yesterday, but I can't gradle sync. I always get

> could not download builder.jar: no cached version available for offline mode

When I get this error in previous version, I just goto **File>Settings>Gradle>Android Studio** and tick use embedded repository. But now I can't find that function in new Android Studio 4.0

Comment: Do you have your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674826/13685592

Comment: Actually I wanna use the embedded builder.jar but no option for that again