# How to add offline Apache Spark dependencies to Java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, gradle

I want to get started with Apache Spark in Java. So I started following [this tutorial](https://www.geekmj.org/apache-spark/java-getting-started-725/). In the tutorial, they have shown a simple desktop app written in Eclipse IDE and compiled and run using the Gradle plugin for Eclipse.

I followed this tutorial, and everything worked perfectly. Here is *their* `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0','junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**So far so good! BUT now my real need was to be able to compile and run Spark applications in an offline system.** So what I did was that I searched for **`org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0`** and **`junit:junit:4.12`** in [**`jcenter`**](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) and downloaded all the `.jar` files and then created a folder in my project root named `libs` and then added all those `.jar` files to my project's Build Path by following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

And I modified the **`build.gradle`** file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

//apply plugin: 'java-library'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

When I compile this modified application, I get the following errors in the console. The question is that what am I doing wrong? How to I get rid of the problem?

```
Working Directory: /home/jason/WorkspaceOfGetStartedWithSparkJava/FirstApacheSparkProjectWithOfflineDependencies
Gradle User Home: /usr/share/gradle/bin
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.3
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: build

:compileJava/home/jason/WorkspaceOfGetStartedWithSparkJava/FirstApacheSparkProjectWithOfflineDependencies/src/main/java/main_package/SparkDriverProgram.java:21: error: cannot access Cloneable
        conf.setAppName("Schneider");
            ^
  class file for scala.Cloneable not found
/home/jason/WorkspaceOfGetStartedWithSparkJava/FirstApacheSparkProjectWithOfflineDependencies/src/main/java/main_package/SparkDriverProgram.java:22: error: cannot access Serializable
        conf.setMaster("local");
            ^
  class file for scala.Serializable not found
2 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Gradle repository for offline development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436473/build-gradle-repository-for-offline-development)

Comment: @user8371915 That one is using Maven, but I am not. Do I need to learn Maven now as well (I am short of time)?

Answer (score 0):

SparkConf implements the interfaces scala.Cloneable and scala.Serializable both of which are not part of org.apache.spark:spark-core but of org.apache.spark:scala-library. If you add that jar to your project the same way your did with the core jar those two errors should disappear.